# Docker: how to mount local folder inside container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I need to share a folder from my OSX machine with a running Docker container, but I can't find how to do it. 
Here's a working Docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
mariadb:
  image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
  environment:
    - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=bitnami
    - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
    - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  volumes:
    - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
phpmyadmin:
  image: 'bitnami/phpmyadmin:4'
  ports:
    - '8081:80'
    - '4430:443'
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
  volumes:
    - 'phpmyadmin_data:/bitnami'
moodle:
  image: 'bitnami/moodle:3'
  environment:
    - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
    - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
    - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
    - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  volumes:
    - 'moodle_data:/bitnami'
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  phpmyadmin_data:
    driver: local
  moodle_data:
    driver: local
```

This file correctly starts 3 Docker containers, 1 for Moodle, 1 for MariaDb and 1 for Phpmyadmin.

What I need to do now is to share the content of a local folder with a folder inside the Moodle container. But I can't figure out how to change the Volumes key to reflect that. I tried with a mapping like:

```
moodle_data:
- moodle_data:/Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle/Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle
```

But it didn't work.. what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance to anybody who can help!

Comment: Hi Giulio, is this correct _/Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle/Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle_? It should be _/Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle/_, right?

Comment: Therefore what is the directory **INSIDE** your Moodle container that you want to map?

Comment: Hi Roberto, sorry I mis-copied that line, it should be 'Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle/'

Comment: Basically I need to be able to write some code in my local machine at  'Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle/' and having transferred in real time inside the container at ':bitnami/moodle/blocks/gatto'. 
I have tried many combinations but none worked

Comment: Great, I'll post an example as a answer and we can discuss it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map your host_folder with your container_folder using host_folder:container_folder. As mentioned on the comments:

```
moodle:
  image: 'bitnami/moodle:3'
  environment:
    - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
    - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
    - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
    - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  volumes: 
    - /Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle:/bitnami/gatto
    - moodle_data:/bitnami
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
```

**Remember: Your folder on host_folder must be acessible by docker daemon**

Comment: Hi Roberto, I have tried exactly that solution... but after 'docker-compose up -d', the container goes up, stays up for a few seconds and immediately shuts down.

Comment: And I have chmodded 777 to my /Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle folder

Comment: Can you do a _docker logs_? Maybe we can find something

Comment: Oh, is  /Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle the **complete directory in your mac**? Like _cd /Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle_ needs to work.

Comment: Yes, it is the complete path. If I search logs for the container I get an application error : "Default exception handler: Plugin "block/gatto" is defective or outdated, can not continue, sorry. Debug: Missing version.php file" . Which seems to be Moodle related, so not a problem with Docker..... mmm

Comment: Yes! It's not a problem with docker anymore, you need to see the latest deploys of Moodle to get it working :). So, assign as the answer to help others on the same path and good luck!

Comment: Ok, but to help the others it must be mentioned that the correct answer is:
volumes:
      - /Users/macbook/Code/Php/moodle-docker/moodle:/bitnami/gatto
      - 'moodle_data:/bitnami'
Therefore, to make it work, BOTH volume must be added.